# How to bind L-click to keybind, but only when not typing (in AHK)?

Tags: autohotkey

I am a total AHK newbie. I just recently discovered the joy of being able to click by binding L-click to a keyboard key. I bound it to my letter "D" key, however I then ran into what should have been an obvious problem of now not being able to type the letter "D" at all. The script I am using is just:

D::LButton

Whenever I try to type "D", it just clicks wherever my mouse is.

Is there a way to bind L-click to my D key, but have it **NOT** trigger when pressing "D" in a typing field (e.g. the URL bar, or when a cell in Google Sheets is double-clicked, or when you press Enter to type in a video game, etc)? I basically want to be able to type "D" when a typing field is focused, while being able to L-click with "D" (i.e. trigger the script) when a typing field is not focused.

If someone could lend some advice, it would be very much appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

AHK v1:

The [#If directive](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v1/lib/_If.htm) creates context-sensitive hotkeys and hotstrings:

```
#Requires AutoHotkey v1.1

#If (A_Cursor != "IBeam") ; the mouse pointer is not in text input mode

    d::LButton
    
#If
```

AHK v2:

The [#HotIf directive](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v2/lib/_HotIf.htm) creates context-sensitive hotkeys and hotstrings:

```
#Requires AutoHotkey v2.0

#HotIf (A_Cursor != "IBeam")

    d::LButton
    
#HotIf
```

Comment: Keywords, examples and descriptions of various cursor types - [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/cursor)

Answer (score 0):

AutoHotKey cannot detect the activity-focused element of programs, as this would be very hard, if not impossible, to implement universally for all applications. Additionally, it very much falls out of the scope of the AHK project.

You have two options; you could detect the active window and maybe only have your hotkey then, or typically this is why hotkeys require you to hold a prefix key such as ctrl, left alt, or right alt, as these don't conflict with existing usage of keys.

You can get the title of the active window with the following method https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v1/lib/WinGetActiveTitle.htm

Answer (score 0):

I do no think this is possible.  Regardless of whether or not you are in a "typing mode" the keyboard is looking for inputs.

There appears to be methods to detect if a key is pressed quickly in rapid succession:  https://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/103198-fast-way-to-detect-double-key-presses/  You could change to script to see if you press <kbd>D</kbd> twice quickly.

Or you can change the <kbd>D</kbd> to use one or more modifier key, like <kbd>ctrl</kbd>, <kbd>alt</kbd>, <kbd>Win</kbd>, or <kbd>shift</kbd>.